# ASP.NET MVC Inline Styling convert

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, stylesheet, styles, inline-styles

Is there anyway I can get the all style of a page (even the style in some linked css files) as inline style?

For example, I have my css file:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>Hello World!</body>
</html>
```

So I'd like to get:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="background-color: red; color: black;">Hello World!</body>
</html>
```

It would also work for me if I can get all the style in a `style` node.

Comment: just using jquery alone? you can basically just open the css file like a normal file and parse it. but i doubt you can do that with just jquery alone. at the very least you might need some flash or java applet. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reading2.htm

Comment: What do you need this for, what is your use case?

Comment: If it is not possible by jQuery alone then I guess I'll have to open the file as you said, I just thought it would be possible. I need this because I'm generating a PDF with this HTML and it doesn't understand the style in linked files but it does understand the style node.

Comment: @melaos, @Pekka: Sorry for what I asked before, I updated my question with what I really need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your comments, what you need is **very different**

What you are looking for is a tool that grabs an HTML page with it's own CSS styling and convert them into **inline styling**.

For that, plenty of tools are at your service:

> http://premailer.dialect.ca/

There are more in [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=inline%20styling%20convert), this is commonly used in Mailing as Email Client Applications do not intrepertate linked CSS but inline css.

Comment: you are right, I'll update the question. Maybe some you'd recommend for ASP.NET, MVC?

Comment: plenty of services out there, use one, like http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/styler/api/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a .NET solution, you might be interested in PreMailer.NET.

https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net

```
PreMailer pm = new PreMailer();
string premailedOutput = pm.MoveCssInline(htmlSource, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I finally (2 years late!) got this up on github and in nuget:

https://github.com/lukeschafer/HtmlCleanser

Note: Premailer.Net (suggested by Arical) does *not inline correctly*.